# JQuery: .index() returns -1

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's main part of html:

```
    <div id="table">
    <div class="table_item">asd</div>
    <div class="table_item">asd</div>
    <div class="table_item">asd</div>
    </div>
```

And JS (JQuery):

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
    $(".table_item").click( function()
    {
        alert($("#table").index($(this)));
    });
});
```

click handling works but I ALWAYS get -1 from .index.

trying simply `$(this).index();` shows the same result.

Please help! What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
    var ti = $('.table_item');
    ti.click( function()
    {
        alert(ti.index(this));
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** Someone had a post that was deleted that was correct, and I think a little better than my code above:

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
    $('.table_item').click( function()
    {
        alert($(this).index());
    });
});
```

Working examples of both solutions: http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/rx5e7/

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `index` on a collection, in this case divs with class `table_item`

```
alert($(".table_item").index(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are attaching a `click()` listener to `$(".table_item")`, you can reference the object by using `$(this)`.

Try:

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
    $(".table_item").click( function()
    {
        alert($(this).index());
    });
});
```